# How to properly connect models in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

In my project I want to have global database of ingredients. I also want for each User to have a possibility to add a ingredient to his own Fridge model but with additional field "numOf". I've stumbled upon errors with PATCH request and im thinking that my database is wrongly connected. Does anyone maybe have a better idea how to arrange my models?

**Ingredient models**

```py
class Ingredient(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class UserIngredient(models.Model):
   ingredient = models.OneToOneField(Ingredient, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   numOf = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

**Fridge model**

```py
class Fridge(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='fridge', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(UserIngredient, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner.username + "'s Fridge"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For example, let 1st user have 2 Apples, 2nd 3 Apples and 3rd 4 Apples in their Fridge. Then in UserIngredient table I have 3 records: Apple 2, Apple 3, Apple 4 which all point to a single Apple Ingredient. How can I avoid this redundancy and just point to a Ingredient instance?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `OneToOneField` to `ForeignKey`  and `ManyToMany` to `ForeignKey` also connect that to `Ingredient` models I think `UserIngredient` is not needed something like this:

```
class Fridge(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    # rest of code

    @property
    def owner_ingredient_count(self):
        return Fridge.objects.filter(owner=self.owner).count()
```

Comment: The ```numOf``` should resemble the number of that ingredient in a fridge. That's why I came up with additional table for how much of that ingredient is stored in that fridge

Comment: Do you want `numOf` to be total number of ingredients across all users or number of ingredients to each user ?

Comment: For each one. For example User A have 4 Apples and User B have 5 Apples

Comment: @Swagnar I have edited my answer with working code

Comment: @swagnar if this fixed your issue do mark my answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change OneToOneField To ForeignKey

```
class Fridge(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='fridge', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(UserIngredient, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.owner.username + "'s Fridge"

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```